# Prove the following limit (only use the limit epsilon delta definition)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to prove the following statement,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{20\sqrt{n-1}}{3n^2} = 0$$

And I am aware that I want to get to $\,\frac{20\sqrt{n-1}}{3n^2}<\epsilon\,$ (epsilon) and then solve for n. However, I don't know how to simplify the expression to solve for n.....

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{20\sqrt{n-1}}{3n^2}<\frac{20\sqrt n}{2n}=\frac{10}{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: I think on the right-hand side of the equality, you mean $10/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton , indeed so.

Comment: This works fine, but the denominator could be $2n^2$ in the center, allowing $n^{3/2}$ at the end if you want.

Comment: I know, but such a basic question seems to imply the OP is beginning with this stuff and the above seems easier to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply the fraction by $$\frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{1/\sqrt{n}}=1$$and recall that $\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt{n}}<1$. This leaves you with your limit as $$0<\frac{20\sqrt{n-1}}{3n^2}<\frac{20}{3n^{3/2}}.$$ The first inequality follows from the fact that all terms are positive, and the second inequality from the observation above. Now, if you can show the limit on the right is zero, the limit in the middle must be zero by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: what if I am only using the epsilon delta definition and not any other theorem; couldn't we try and estimate the left side of the inequality (basically not to use other theorems)?

Comment: @Walker:  using the epsilon definition you just need to come up with an $n$ when given an $\epsilon$ that works.  So from here you want $\frac {20}{3n^{3/2}} \lt \epsilon$ which requires $n \gt \left(\frac {20}{3\epsilon }\right)^{\frac 23}$